# Add typings reference in Node library

Tags: node.js, typescript

I created a NodeJS library in plain JS and I added typings which work fine when installing the library in another project using `npm|yarn`.

But when referencing the library in its own directory e.g. for tests, neither WebStorm nor VS Code recognise the types for Code Completion / IntelliSense (hovering over the methods states there are no definitions found for them).

My lib (`./index.js`):

```
const port = function (number) {
};

module.exports = { port };
```

The typings (`./index.d.ts`):

```
declare module "my-module" {
    interface MyModule {
        port(number: number): void;
    }

    const _: MyModule;
    export = _;
}
```

I tried adding references in my tests file (`test/index.js`) like this but it didn't solve it:

```
/// <reference types="../index.d.ts" /> 
const myLib = require('../')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from `declare module "my-module"`. It's unnecessary to name the module when the typing is located in the package. Additionally, the syntax of a non-standard export `export = _;` is not required in your case because your package contains a regular named export. Just export it. I suggest:

```
// index.d.ts
export declare function port(number: number): void;
// … you can add other named exports like:
export declare function user(name: string): void;
// or even (it's equivalent):
export declare const user2: (name: string) => void;
// etc.
```

This typing will work as a package typing if the file is referenced by `"types"` in the `package.json` file. It'll work too when the `./index` file is imported because it shares the same name.

Notice: TypeScript follows the [ES6 module syntax](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/).

Comment: This seems to work now but but what happens if I have multiple functions in my lib and I have an `interface` for my lib like this: `{port(number:number):void, user(name: string):void}`